# dev c++ doesnt highlight syntax mistakes and errors

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to coding and just moved to dev c++ and it never notifies me when I write something wrong or if it doesnt make sense. When I was using visual c++ the second I wrote something wrong or if a library was missing it would highlight it and if I hovered over it it would give me an error message....is there anyway to get that with dev c++?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with DevC++ is DevC++. Completely opinionated but I recommend you switch to Code::Blocks soon. Make sure you've opened a .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

According to this pdf
http://www.apeg.ac.me/nastava/Introduction%20to%20DevC-%20IDE.pdf

The editor highlights with different colors keywords and other elements of the C language. The classic scheme uses:

1. Light blue for comments
2. Green for included libraries
3. Red for text strings
4. Bold black for C keywords

As long as you are using the classic scheme then your errors should be obvious if they do not show up with the expected syntax color. You can check in Tools > Editor options >
Syntax > Color Speed Settings > Classic

I would also expect you are able to tweak these how ever you want in the Tools > Editor options > Syntax area. I am not sure what version you are using as you did not state it.

Comment: I'm not sure it just says dev c++ I assume the newest one since I dled it today. so theres no way for it to notify me say I missed a semicolon or something like that? the same issue with code::blocks

Comment: Have you gone in the editor options and tried to customize your ide at all? It is not updated like other IDE's so if it isn't an available options and you want to use it I would look in to switching IDE. Also, what is the issue you have with Visual Studio?

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'm trying to figure out the difference between an IDE and a compiler...I'v been just learning syntax I didnt study this stuff at all. The problem with Visual studio is I tried deleting it to install a clean version but for some reason the installer thinks its still on my computer and the remove software thinks its still there but when I click to uninstall the program crashes...so I'm at a loss of what to do here

Comment: This is a simple explanation of the difference between IDK and Compiler http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/o8TbqMoL/

Comment: Oh, between dev c++ and Visual Studio, I'd prefer VS, I use it at home and at work, so hopefully you can figure out how to reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks jeff I'll take a read now, I edited my response to include what happened with VS

Comment: Thanks...its frustrating..I'm considering reformatting my computer because of this

Comment: When you say you deleted it, does that mean you deleted the folder or did you uninstall it from the control panel?

Comment: In that case I'd suggest going to your control panel and removing the program. At that point I think you would be able to reinstall.